# conda install rapids fail date to package

Tags: linux, installation, package, conda, rapids

I tried installing rapids library on a conda environment but getting the following error

```
conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge rapids=21.10.00
```

```
    PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - rapids=21.10.00 -> cucim=21.10 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']
  - rapids=21.10.00 -> cucim=21.10 -> cudatoolkit=11.4
  - rapids=21.10.00 -> cucim=21.10 -> libcucim=21.10.00

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

I have added the following channels to my conda :

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  - rapidsai
  - nvidia
```

and my conda version is : `conda 4.6.14` , and I am running conda on server with OS :

```
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

I tried installing packages individually (cuml, cuDF) but getting similar errors.
any thoughts on how I can fix this

Comment: Maybe try `CONDA_CHANNEL_PRIORITY=flexible conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge rapids=21.10.00`

Answer (score 0):

Please update conda and retry.  That sometimes fixes these kinds of problems, especially with such an old version. Your version was released 2 years and 5 months ago.  Latest is `4.10.3`,  You can get miniconda here: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Also, you can just use `rapids=21.10` instead of `rapids=21.10.00`.  If, for whatever reason, there is a hotfix released, you'll probably want it.